# Disable libre office upgrades

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

Each time I `sudo apt-get upgrade`  I can see many updates from libreoffice packages. Since I have a limited memory laptop, I would like to "disable" the upgrades for all the libreoffice packages (libreoffice-writer, libreoffice-pdfimport...).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `sudo apt-mark hold package-name ...` will keep the current version of one or more packages. For example, see [PinningHowTo - Introduction to Holding Packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages) and [How To Exclude Packages from Apt-Get Upgrade](https://tecadmin.net/exclude-packages-from-apt-upgrade/).

Presumably, `"^libreoffice*"` (quotes included) will select all packages beginning with `libreoffice` when using `apt-mark`, as it would with `apt-get`, but I wasn't able to locate an explicit example to this effect.

Comment: ```sudo apt-mark hold "^libreoffice*"``` worked, thanks :)